# how I can separate a section of site if i have other section of this?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, rss

i create a site with asp.NET webform app that get URLs of News website RSS and check them Tandem to find new news and save title,url of news, Description into Database ...
now I want to save Deatails in Database .
But any Web Agency not save deatalis in RSS .
I can find Description of news in Rss and then I want to find Deatails in the news page . something like Crawler .
so i find description in RSS : 
[image]

and wanna to find deatails in page :

[image]

so I need answer to 2 questions :
1- How I can find source of the webpage with URL ?
2- How I can remove the HTML tag from it and find deatails ?
do you have any idea for do this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Getting HTML code from a website. You can use code like this.

```
using System.Net;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://somesite.com/default.html");
}
```

and then you can find any thing from this string

**Update**

To remove html tags from string

```
String result = Regex.Replace(htmlCode, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
```

Comment: so How i can remove all html tag from this String ?

Comment: thanks a lot :) if I accept and check your answer nobody answer to other my question ...

Comment: why it does not Support utf-8 strings ? how I can solve it ? the result like : Congratulations, you\'ve reached the end of the internet.', msgText: 'Loading the next set of posts...', ajaxTimeout: 'Loading seems to be taking a while...', pageNotFound: 'Page not found', pageNotFoundDesc: '404 Not FoundSorry, this page cannot be found.' }; Ø²ÙˆÙ…ÛŒØª Ø²ÙˆÙ…ÛŒØª Ù†ÙˆÛŒØ³Ù†Ø¯Ú¯Ø§Ù† Ø²ÙˆÙ…ÛŒØª ÙˆØ¨ Ù„ÛŒÙ†Ú© Ù†Ø¸Ø±Ø³Ù†Ø¬ÛŒ Ø¬Ø³ØªØ¬Ùˆ

Comment: you have another issue ask another question , and by the way people here are not to solve your assignment , you should google or debug that first by yourself